# Encrypting Web.config, single server

Tags: asp.net, security, sharepoint, web-config

This might be a stupid question, but:

I have a SharePoint application that operates from a single server. I have encrypted my connectionString with `RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider` in machine-level:

```
aspnet_regiis -pc "MyKeyPair" -exp
```

and granted anonymous access to it.

Does it decrypt for all users that log in and try to use the application, regardless of a computer?

Answer (score 1):

Every time a user interacts with the application, your connection string will be decrypted using your server's machine key when db access is required. It doesn't matter what computer the user is using, the user could be on the server itself, or browsing from halfway across the world.